# HTTPS not working with WordPress click to deploy

Tags: wordpress, cloud, google-cloud-platform

I installed WordPress in Google Cloud Plattform using the feature "Click to Deploy".

But I need my website work with HTTPS. So I get a certificate with Let's encrypt and I followed the instructions in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl to install it. All the process was successful but when I try to use my site with HTTPS I get the error "the site refused the connection".

This page https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely says an option is use load balancing, but I believe I don't need that.

I applied this others instructions unsuccessfully:

- www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress
- www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-install-wordpress-on-google-cloud-and-why-thats-awesome
- stackoverflow.com/questions/30075971/google-cloud-platform-cannot-get-https-ssl-working-on-wordpress-instance

My site works fine with HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem with this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kLvD2mlmlk

The difference is I had to upload my crt and key files generated by Let's encrypt.

It was very difficult for me because I am not familiar with linux.

Regards.